# Finding nearest value on another table

Tags: sql, apache-drill

I need to find nearest value of one table to another table.

For example, I need to match Product from Table New_Price using its Price values by checking its nearest value on the table Actual_Price

Table New_Price

| Product | Price |
| --- | --- |
| X | 2.0 |
| Z | 3.0 |

Table Actual_Price

| Product_Desc | Price |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 1.2 |
| EFG | 3.4 |

Planned Result:

| Product | Price | Product Desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2.0 | ABG |
| Z | 3.0 | EFG |

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you have attempted to solve this yourself, it's good practice to include your work here, or a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think a correlated subquery does what you want:

```
select np.*,
       (select ap.product_desc
        from actual_price ap
        order by abs(ap.price - np.price)
        limit 1
       ) as product_desc
from new_price np;
```

Comment: Thanks! I also thought this should work. However, I tried and it apache drill returns error:  Query Execution Error: System Error: Cannotplanexecption: Node could not be implemented. Checked this error and its about queries with complex expression in lateral and unnest fails with cannotplanexecption.

Answer (score 0):

You can cross join or left join the both price table with a windowed function order by the minimal absolute delta between prices. That could give :

```sql
WITH old_near AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT Actual_Price.Product_Desc, 
          FIRST_VALUE(New_Price.Product) OVER (PARTITION BY Actual_Price.Product_Desc ORDER BY ABS(New_Price.Price - Actual_Price.Price)) new_product
     FROM Actual_Price LEFT JOIN New_Price ON TRUE)
SELECT New_Price.*, old_near.Product_Desc
  FROM New_Price LEFT JOIN old_near ON old_near.new_product = New_Price.Product;
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried and it returns error query cannot be planned possibly due to either a cartesian join or inequality join

Comment: @MargearyGg Can you give us the drill version ? To make cross join you have to _"As a workaround, set the planner.enable_multiphase_agg option to false"_ as stated by the [documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/from-clause/).